# Why does my paralelization approach not scale?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

- I have to iterate over a large collection (> 50GB).
- I am using a cursor and multiprocessing pool with a queue as a communication tool.

  - It's slow (1500 documents/sec approximately).

Can I somehow speed up the processing in tradeoff for more memory usage?

```
def dowork(args):

    uid = int(args.get('uid'))
    if map_userid_visits.get(uid):
        map_userid_visits[uid] += 1
    else:
        map_userid_visits[uid] = 1

def main():

    manager = Manager()
    map_userid_visits = manager.dict()
    start_time = time.time()
    print ('Start Time', start_time)
    cur = cursor.Cursor(mycollection)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(CONFIG_POOL_SIZE)
    iteration = 0
    for user_event in cur:
        pool.apply(dowork, (user_event, ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print map_userid_visits
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't scale. The main problem is that you are sending one row at a time only so that you can do a very lightweight operation. This means the serialization overhead is much bigger than the work itself.

Also from [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply):

> `apply(func[, args[, kwds]])¶`
>
> Call func with arguments args and keyword arguments kwds. **It blocks until the result is ready**. Given this blocks, apply_async() is better suited for performing work in parallel. Additionally, func is only executed in one of the workers of the pool.

Comment: Thanks @Ente, Its just doubled my processing speed.